# Definitions of fairness

Tags: ethics, history-of-philosophy

I am not a philosophy scholar, but I'm looking for - relatively recent and well-accepted - definitions of the notion of fairness. John Rawls, for example, outlines what he believes is fair in "A theory of Justice" and I imagine other philosophers must have given this a try. Unfortunately it's the only definition I'm aware of and would like to expand/update my knowledge on the topic. I am also fine with criteria that establish whether something can be considered fair or not, rather than strict definitions of the concept.